# Passing of model from razor to javascript - very strange error

Tags: javascript, sql-server, entity-framework, razor, nvarchar

I tried to pass the selected model in the HTML table row right into javascript function, including conversion to a JSON. The conversion failed because of the problem below.
Also, I freaked out for more than 6 hours trying to understand why it's not working. Now I know what caused the problem, no idea how to fix it.
Here is what I tried (simple and easy):

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead align="center">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">AssetID</th>
        <th scope="col">Loaction</th>
        <th scope="col">AreaIn</th>
        <th scope="col">Rooms</th>
        <th scope="col">ImageURL</th>
        <th scope="col">Action</th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody align="center">

    @foreach (var a in @Model.OwnAssetsList)
    {

        String[]  assetArray = new String[8] { a.AssetID.ToString(), a.OwnerID.ToString(), a.OwnerPublicKey.ToString(), a.Loaction.ToString(), a.AreaIn.ToString(), a.Rooms.ToString(), a.ImageURL.ToString(), a.Price.ToString() };
        <tr>
            <td>@a.AssetID</td>
            <td>@a.Loaction</td>
            <td>@a.AreaIn</td>
            <td>@a.Rooms</td>
            <td><a target="_blank" href=@a.ImageURL>Click</a></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong" onclick="offerContract(@a.Loaction/* or @a.ImageURL*/)">Offer Contract</button></td>

        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

In Javascript:

```
@section scripts
{
<script type="text/javascript">
    function offerContract(param)
    {    
        document.getElementById("dialogAssetID").innerHTML = "Asset No:".bold()+param.AssetID;
        document.getElementById("dialogOwnerAddress").innerHTML="Your Public Key:" +param.OwnerID;
  }               
</script>
}
```

The javascript function fails if and only if I passing @a.Loaction or @a.ImageURL.
Here is the error in the console: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list'. 
[image]

The rest properties of the model passed successfully.
The '@a.Loaction' and '@a.ImageURL' working fine in the HTML table
I am adding now the model and the table scheme:

```
public class Asset
{
    [Key]
    public int AssetID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int OwnerID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string OwnerPublicKey { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Loaction { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int AreaIn { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Rooms { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ImageURL { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public double Price { get; set; }
    }
```

[image]

I will appreciate any help. More than 6 hours spent on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

in your Razor page, you basically need to pre-generate a javascript object that you will then pass along to your JS:

in your scripts section is a good place:

```
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var data = @Json.Serialize(@Model.OwnAssetsList);
        function offerContract(index)
        {           
            document.getElementById("dialogAssetID").innerHTML = "Asset No:".bold() + data[index].assetId;
            document.getElementById("dialogOwnerAddress").innerHTML="Your Public Key:" + data[index].ownerId;
        }
    </script>
```

Your Razor then could look something like this (note, since you are opting for foreach, there was no direct way to get current iteration index, so I had to introduce one myself):

```
@{var i = 0} //
@foreach (var a in @Model.OwnAssetsList)
{
    <tr>
        ...
        <td><button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong" onclick="offerContract(@i)">Offer Contract</button></td>         
    </tr>
    i += 1; // next iteration
}
}
```

UPD: if you absolutely must pass strings from Razor to JS, you will need to quote them:

```
<td><button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong" onclick="offerContract('@a.Loaction')">Offer Contract</button></td>
```

I suggest single quotes so Razor does not get confused

Comment: I'm sorry I assumed you're running project on asp.net 4.x. what's your environment then?

Comment: Asp.net 4.5 I guess

Comment: And I`m using mvc core 3.0 on VS2019

Comment: `@Json.Serialize()` is available in ASP.NET Core and it's doing the same. I updated the answer

Comment: The function didn`t recognize it

Comment: can you elaborate a bit on what exactly the error was?

Comment: I think I know what is the problem. It seems that the javascript function cannot read the '@a.Loaction' and '@a.ImageURL'. No idea why

Comment: Both of them are string.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You mind updating your question with reproducible code example? Also check what the serialised JSON looks like - I suspect it's going to be camelCased by convention, so your `ImageURL` will become `imageUrl` and `Loaction` will be `loaction`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203633/discussion-between-timur-and-haim).

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to pass the problematic properties:

```
<tbody align="center">
    @{ int i = 0;}
    @foreach (var a in @Model.OwnAssetsList)
    {
        string loaction = "loc" + i;
        string url = "url" + i;

        <tr>
            <td>@a.AssetID</td>
            <td id=@loaction>@a.Loaction</td>
            <td>@a.AreaIn</td>
            <td>@a.Rooms</td>
            <td><a id=@url target="_blank" href=@a.ImageURL>Click</a></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong" onclick="offerContract( @i)">Offer Contract</button></td>
        </tr>
        i++;
    }

</tbody>
```

And in the function:

```
 function offerContract(param)
    {        
        var idLoac = "#loc" + param;
        var idUrl = "#url" + param;
        var demdloc = $(idLoac).text();
        var demdurl = $(idUrl).attr("href");
        document.getElementById("dialogAssetID").innerHTML = "Asset No:".bold() + demdloc;
        document.getElementById("dialogOwnerID").innerHTML = "Your ID:".bold() + demdurl;
    }
```

And the properties are perfectly passing.